# How to filter array of file paths using array of file names

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Using lodash, how can I filter out the array of file paths using the array of file names?

```
var imageNames = ['/Users/x/edm/images/advertiser.jpg', '/Users/x/edm/images/advertiser_mob.jpg', '/Users/x/edm/images/app_store_button.jpg', '/Users/x/edm/images/header.jpg'];

var usedImageNames = ['app_store_button.jpg', 'advertiser.jpg'];

_.mixin({
  findArrayItemsUsingArray: function (collection, values) {
    return _.filter(collection, function (fileName) {
      _.each(values, function (imageName) {
        if (_.endsWith(fileName, imageName))
          return true;
      });
    })
  }
})

console.log(_.findArrayItemsUsingArray(imageNames, usedImageNames));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming POSIX filepaths (separated with `/`):

In ES6:

```
imageNames.filter(path => {
  let parts = path.split('/')
  let file = parts[parts.length -1]
  return usedImageNames.indexOf(file) !== -1
})
```

In ES5:

```
imageNames.filter(function (path) {
  var parts = path.split('/')
  var file = parts[parts.length -1]
  return usedImageNames.indexOf(file) !== -1
})
```

In Lodash:

```
_.filter(imageNames, function (path) {
  return _.includes(usedImageNames, _(path).split('/').last())
})
```

In Lodash + ES6:

```
imageNames.filter(path => _.includes(usedImageNames, _(path).split('/').last()))
```

You *could* do the comparison with `_.endsWith()`, but consider what would happen if you had `/path/to/somefilename.jpg` and `/path/to/filename.jpg` in the `imageNames` array, but only `filename.jpg` in the `usedImageNames` one.

Similarly, you could also use something like `.endsWith('/' + name)`, but I preferred the split-and-last approach for clarity.

I've done some [performance testing](https://jsperf.com/so-34233539). Conclusion: don't use Lodash ;) This version with regexp is sometimes slightly faster, but its lack of clarity is probably not worth it:

```
imageNames.filter(function(path) {
  return usedImageNames.indexOf(path.match(/\/([^/]+)$/)[1]) !== -1
})
```

Comment: An amazing and well detailed answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objArray = imageNames.map(function(path) {
  var splitted = path.split("/");
  return {name: splitted[splitted.length - 1],
          path: path};
});

_.sort(objArray, "name");
```